# Accuracy graph for neural network is fluctuating a lot

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network

I've made a neural network and it's architecture is as follows:

It has two two branches that are merged. One branch takes matrices as an input to a convolutional network and other branch is a fully connected layer that takes a vector as an input. These two branches are merged and send to a fully connected layer followed by a output layer. My network runs, however, I get the following graphs:

For accuracy:

[image]

For Loss:

[image]

I think my loss graph is alright. But the accuracy fun is fluctuating a lot. My overall accuracy is 60%. Do you think these graphs suggests under-fitting or it's normal?  Insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a common behaviour to have fluctuations due to batch training. A perfect smooth loss graph/increase in accuracy would be obtained if and only if the neural network would be fed the entire dataset (this is impossible from a computational viewpoint).

When your training loss increases, the validation accuracy decreases, which is a good sign. The last graph together with my previous observation eliminates the possibility of overfitting(at least on the development set).

The graphs do not look out of the ordinary (except for those spikes that I have already mentioned, it is normal to have them during batch training)

It may or may not be the case of underfitting. If using more complex neural networks on both branches(on even on one of the branch) gives you a better result, then this means that it is a case of underfitting.

However, this underfitting phenomenon has nothing to do with the spikes that you see on the graphs.

Hope this helps you with your problem :)

Comment: Thank you. It makes a lot of sense.